# SSAS dimension design - new vs existing customer

Tags: ssas, cube

I'm very new to SSAS and would like to pick you experts' brains.

I'm working on changing existing cubes.  One of the cube is for getting customers and sales
data, e.g. sales by customers for Q1 2012, etc.  I want to add a grouping for new or existing customer base on customer create date, like below:

```
Q1 2012
-------
New customers           2500
  Customer Name 1       1000
  Customer Name 2       1500
Existing Customers      5500
  Customer Name 3       4500
  Customer Name 4       1000
```

When the filter changed from Q1 2012 to Q2 2012, customer name 1 and name 2 would be under existing customer grouping.

I have customer dimension, sales measures but can't figure out how I can incorporate new/existing customer into customer dimension.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/counting-new-and-returning-customers-in-mdx/) by Chris Webb should help you on your way.